# How do you use Custom URL as HTTP Request in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How do you use Custom URL as HTTP Request in Azure Logic App? [Logic App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1E7f.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to this is to [put the LA behind an API Management instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-logic-app-as-api). This isn't exactly an inexpensive approach, but it satisfies your requirement, as APIM can support custom domains.

A cheaper way is to build an API and host it in an App Service. That API would invoke the LA http endpoint when called.

Comment: Thanks @josh That seems like the way to go... So then let me ask this. Can I take the custom URL and create an Alias Domain from it using GoDaddy, etc?